# Find and process alternatives held by list of std::variants

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's have a very simple element template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Element
{
    int id;
    T value;
};
```

and a template function processing two of them:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename R>
R DoSomething(T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2)
{
    ; // do something with t1 and t2
}
```

I need to store different lists of elements having the same time,
so I defined these type aliases (to keep vectors of the same type
in separate lists):

```
using IntListT = std::list<std::vector<Element<int>>>;
using DblListT = std::list<std::vector<Element<double>>>;
using StrListT = std::list<std::vector<Element<std::string>>>;
```

to hold all the elements in a single class member I use this map:

```
using ListVariantT = std::variant<IntListT, DblListT, StrListT>;
std::map<std::type_index, ListVariantT> myElements;
```

Question:
My member function receives two element ID's (two ints, of course).
How to find the two requested elements and pass them to DoSomething func?

I definitely DO NOT insist on storing all elements in a single map or using std::variant at all. But storing Elements in (many) different vectors should be preserved due to performance reasons...

Many thanks to all

EDIT:

- all ID's are UNIQUE across all `Element<T>`'s. So ID unambiguously identifies an element
- operators and result types of operations between types are given by system's design (by specializing standard operators for type `Element<T>`), hence template param  R is pointless in actual code (was used just for illustration and completeness)
- std::visit doesn't help much here. I need to find two different elements (or references to them) of (eventually) different types and then pass them to DoSomething() function.
- "performance reasons" is hard to explain without diving into details. I have lot of different homogeneous vectors of Elements of the same type, which I process in different ways. Usually iterating and doing some math/statistics/transformations/etc. Now I'm extending the functionality to support operations across different types of Elements. E.g. if  I have vector of `Element<int>` and `Element<double>`, I should be able to accumulate all elements into a new vector of `Element<double>`. Alternatively, if user chooses an Element E1, another element E2, passes me their ID's, I should be able to find them and to return E1+E2, maybe E1*E2, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?  In particular, can you also show the caller code?

Comment: Maybe start without a map or variant at all. Just given a `std::list<std::vector<Element<std::string>>>`, how do you plan on finding the Element with a particular ID efficiently?

Comment: Are you familiar with [std::visit()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)? This is what it's for.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your "performance reason"?

Comment: So can we assume that the two `int`s passed in are telling you the type (int/double/string) and the `id` of the element? Does the calling site know what type it is expecting?

Comment: @L.F.: I don't have any example, I'm actually asking for it. This question is not sort of "this code doesn't work", it's much more "HOW to do it?"

Comment: Still, we need some kind of example to actually understand what you are trying to do.  Right now we cannot make much sense of your code because it is too isolated.

Comment: You might want to look into using std::deque instead.
The storage inside deque is often blocks of a fixed size, expanding as needed. The expansion of std::vector is often x2, x2, x2 whereas the expansion of std::deque is often just N + C.

Deque doesn't invalidate pointers, this is evidance that its storage is not contigious. Also, that way maybe you can stop using std::vector inside std::list.